# For polytopes, does union and linear transformation commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, projective-geometry, polyhedra

Given two (convex) polytopes $P_1$ and $P_2$ and a linear transformation $T$, is it true that:
$$T(P_1 \cup P_2) = TP_1 \cup TP_2$$

What if $P_1$ and $P_2$ are not convex?

Comment: $f(X\cup Y)=f(X)\cup f(Y)$ is true for any function $f$.